# Hierarchical vs. Short-Circuit assignment in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, conditional-statements, teradata

Does SQL have both a short-circuit and a hierarchical multi-evaluation syntax?

Example of short-circuit assignment.  Here `decision` gets the FIRST *** clause when ... is true:

## Short-circuit

```
   case  
     when (...) then (***) 
     when (...) then (***)
     when (...) then (***)
     else (...)
   end as decision
```

Example of hierarchical assignment.  Here `decision` gets LAST *** expression when ... is true.

## Hierarchical

```
    if (...) then (decision = ***) end
    if (...) then (decision = ***) end
    if (...) then (decision = ***) end
```

## Inter-Conversion

It is clear that reversing the ordering of the expressions switches between hierarchical and short-circuit. I'm wondering whether SQL also has a construct that would assign the LAST tr expression?

## Test Case:

The following gives a very simple toy example:

```
select 
  flag1, flag2, flag3,
  case
     when flag1=1 and flag2=0 then 'LEFT'
     when flag1=0 and flag2=0 then 'NONE'
     when flag2=0 and flag3=1 then 'RIGHT'
  end as decision 
FROM 
( select 
  1 as flag1, 0 as flag2, 1 as flag3
  -- from dual                               -- if you use Oracle
) tmp ;
```

Short-circuit SQL would return 'LEFT'

An hierarchical assignment would return 'RIGHT'.

**Edit:** You can run this example in [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/703) by clicking on the link.  (Thanks to ypercube for pointing out that useful site! (+1))

Comment: The last example is nice (but it would give error in SQL).

Comment: @ypercube:  I ran it successfully in Teradata SQL and verified that it gives LEFT.  Then ran it again with flag1 set to 0, and it returns NONE... which definitely confirms that SQL's case/when construct is short-circuit.  What SQL are you running it in?  What error did it give you?

Comment: Try it at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/698)** All 4 DBMS (SQL-Server, Postgres, Oracle, MySQL) will result in error (your query is the second one).

Comment: @AKE For [oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/6028) you have a missing `from table`..

Comment: Hmmm, you're both right.  Apparently, Teradata is quite easygoing in what it accepts!  Too bad there isn't a Teradata option in SQL-Fiddle.  I'll edit the example so it works in SQL-Fiddle.

Comment: @ypercube: What a useful site!  I'll definitely be favouriting SQL-Fiddle. Thanks for that link.

Comment: @AKE . . . Out of curiousity, why are you looking for this functionality?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: It was as much out of curiousity myself.  The problem arose while developing a classification algorithm in SQL that uses an hierarchical filter / finite state machine.  While debugging, I discovered my mistaken assumption that `case / when` is hierarchical, not short-circuit.  The most convenient fix would have been to switch to an hierarchical construct.  Since I couldn't find one, I reversed the order of the filter, which solved the practical problem.  But that left the academic problem rolling around my head: don't all reasonable programming languages have both constructs?...

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: In Teradata you can reuse an alias in any place (with some scoping rules), it's very nice and you get used to it very fast (this is because Teradata is older than Standard SQL and used to implement a QUEL-based language before). But it breaks all the rules, of course :-)

Comment: @AssadEbrahim: What programming language allows this using a single expression like `CASE`, multiple `IF` are something totally different. And you need to write the conditons in the right order anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no expression that would do the Hierarchal assignment in one select but it can be achieved just like any other programming language through multiple if statements

```
DECLARE @flag1 BIT = 1, @flag2 BIT = 0, @flag3 BIT = 1, @decision VARCHAR(50)

IF @flag1 = 1 AND @flag2 = 0
    SET @decision = 'LEFT'

IF @flag1 = 0 AND @flag2 = 0
    SET @decision = 'NONE'

IF @flag2 = 0 AND @flag3 = 1
    SET @decision = 'RIGHT'

SELECT @decision
```

Comment: But this will work if you have only one row. It wouldn't work with a table.

Answer (score -1):

For SQL this is not very important as you you end up with just ONE value in `CASE WHEN` clause. So all you need to do is to rearrange your conditions.

In other languages you do some calculations that are stored in variables etc, in *pure* SQL it is not the case.

Comment: I read the question. How exactly are you planning to assign a value to a variable in pure SQL? That is exactly why this question is irrelevant for SQL or you need to make it more clear.

Comment: Your point about the variables is fine, but I knew that already -- the question was quite clear: looking for whether SQL has a construct in which hierarchical evaluation is possible.  See Bassam's answer.  (FYI -- it's sometimes all in how you say something, so 'irrelevant' may just mean you can't see the point or the solution...)

Comment: I still don't see the point of hierarchical evaluation if you can just rearrange your SQL. It will get you the same results and therefore it is irrelevant whether SQL has it or not. I did not mean to be rude by 'irrelevant', it is just not important if it makes it sound better.

Comment: No point -- I was interested in knowing whether SQL as a language has the capability.  Pragmatically, rearrangement is clear and so that was not the issue.  Bassam's answer shows that SQL is no different from any other programming language in what it can do -- that's what I was after.  Anyway, thanks for your comments.  Cheers

Comment: Ok, I understand. I think if you mention PL/SQL or T-SQL in the question then it will make more sense. I am very fanatical about SQL, sorry )

Comment: T-SQL is already in the tag, along with Teradata SQL.  But no worries!  (If you're not happy with the -1, feel free to edit your answer.  This will unlock it, and I can remove the unhelpful marker.)